# How to check if data is in Table

Tags: c#

I have a Windows Form Program which places IDs from 2 tables and places them in another one. I am altering code in which I have from a different project. I need it to check if the IDs are already in the other table and if not place them in it. This is the code I have.

```
    private void btnAllocate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if
            (DM.dtEquipment.Rows[cmEquipment.Position]["Status"].ToString() == "Pending")
            {
                DataRow newServiceTypeEquipment = DM.dtServiceTypeEquipment.NewRow();
                newServiceTypeEquipment["EquipmentID"] = dgvEquipment["EquipmentID", cmEquipment.Position].Value;
                newServiceTypeEquipment["ServiceTypeID"] = dgvServiceType["ServiceTypeID", cmServiceType.Position].Value;
                DM.dsGreens.Tables["ServiceTypeEquipment"].Rows.Add(newServiceTypeEquipment);
                DM.UpdateServiceTypeEquipment();
            }else{
                MessageBox.Show("Cannot allocate treatments to paid visits.", "Error");
            }
        }
        catch
        (ConstraintException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This treatment has already been allocated to this visit.", "Error");
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You forgot to describe a problem or ask a question.

Comment: I have 3 DataGridViews and I need to find out if the selected 2 IDs in the Equipment and ServiceType tables are in the other table. the code
        (DM.dtEquipment.Rows[cmEquipment.Position]["Status"].ToString() == "Pending") is not what I need but was in the original program